# Extending root partition Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: partitioning, gparted, root

I've run out of space on my root partition and I want to extend it. I've seen another posts of this topic but my lack of knowledge makes it difficult for me to achieve what i want. Here's a screenshot of my GParted Window:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't resize the root partition while you're in Ubuntu.  You must use the [GParted Live CD/USB](http://gparted.org/livecd.php), and then, according to your picture, shrink `sda5` and grow `sda9`

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you can't resize partitions while you are using them. To resize root partition, boot via [Ubuntu LiveUSB/DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) or dedicated [GParted Live CD/USB](http://gparted.org/livecd.php).
If you use Ubuntu liveUSB/DVD, open the terminal and type

> sudo apt install gparted

Then, open gparted and shrink (top menu - Partition->resize) the partition you don't need to be so big (not SWAP!) and then extend `sda9`.

Then apply changes and wait for them to finish.